# valid function is not working help needed

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I want to do model validation for my registration form and for that I had done the required coding But my valid function is not working. The suggestion for a valid function is not being shown in my visual studio?
Here is the code:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>

         $("#register").click(function (e) {
                if ($('#frm').valid {
                     $.post("https://localhost:44347/api/Values/Insert", $("#form").serialize(), function (data) {
                    alert('Registered');
                    window.location.href = "/Home/Index/";
                });
                }

            });

        </script>
    }
```

If the form is valid then only it needs to be entered into the if function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$('#frm').valid()` to  fire client-side validation like

```
<form id="frm" asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="register" value="register" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
 </form>

@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#register").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $form = $('#frm');
                if ($form.valid()) {
                    alert("success");
                } else {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            })
        });
</script>
}
```